# Uncaught TypeError: THREE.MTLLoader is not a constructor 2.0

Tags: typescript, three.js, objloader

I earlier asked this question in here: [Uncaught TypeError: THREE.MTLLoader is not a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989337/uncaught-typeerror-three-mtlloader-is-not-a-constructor)

Where I got it to work by changing the three-mtl-loader file. But as I am going to upload my work to github later, I have to create a solution without changing these files.

I am therefore instead trying to load in the obj and mtl files using the loaders used in the classic example: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html

But I still get the error 'Uncaught TypeError: THREE.MTLLoader is not a constructor'

I am a bit unsure about how I would load in these loaders, but right now my code looks like this:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import {OBJLoader} from 'three'
import {MTLLoader} from 'three'


var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
mtlLoader.load("http://blabla.obj.mtl", function(materials) {
   materials.preload();
   var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
   objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
   objLoader.load("http://blabla.obj", function(object) {

       object.scale.x = scale;
       object.scale.y = scale;
       object.scale.z = scale;

       scene.add(object)

  });
});
```

Where in the three.js file in the src folder I have inserted:

```
export { OBJLoader } from './loaders/OBJLoader.js'
export { MTLLoader} from './loaders/MTLLoader.js'
```

**EDIT**

I installed using NPM, and the error disappears. Unfortunately other issues occur - but I have asked these in a different question: [three-mtl-loader error: THREE.MeshPhongMaterial: .shading has been removed -> object not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753533/three-mtl-loader-error-three-meshphongmaterial-shading-has-been-removed-ob)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Three.js docs are misleading. Even though the [MTLLoader is in the main documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/MTLLoader), it's actually not part of Three.js's core library. It's included in the `examples/` folder of Three.js.

If you're using ES6 module syntax, you have two options.

## Option 1: NPM

Usually people publish things like this to NPM because the creators of Threejs don't use modern JS development practices. In this case, there is a [three-mtl-loader npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-mtl-loader) package.

```
npm install --save three-mtl-loader
```

and then

```
import MTLLoader from 'three-mtl-loader';
```

## Option 2: Copy MTLLoader from Three's source.

You can copy the [MTLLoader.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/MTLLoader.js) file into your project, but it's not good practice to copy third party libraries into your local project if you're using modern ES6 modules.

Comment: Do you mean that I also import this: import * as THREE from 'three'

Comment: Do you mean like this? :`console.log(MTLLoader);`

`var mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();`      The console returns 'undefined' and now the error is instead: Uncaught TypeError: three_3.MTLLoader is not a constructor

Comment: Is it then because it isn't properly installed or something? Because if I e.g. `console.log` Textureloader, which is in the same folder of loaders, I get an output

Comment: Deleted my comments and updated the question. I forgot it's not in three core.

Comment: Thank you very much - but as stated in my old question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989337/uncaught-typeerror-three-mtlloader-is-not-a-constructor), my original problem was that I had installed it using npm, but that I would then still get the error mentioned in the title - But if you can see how I can use that package, without having to edit the three-mtl-loader file myself, then that would be a MAJOR help :D

Comment: Weird - I just reinstalled using npm, and suddenly it works! But thank you so much for the help, you are my hero :D

Comment: I created a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753533/three-mtl-loader-error-three-meshphongmaterial-shading-has-been-removed-ob) - as new questions emerged when I installed using npm - I would be forever grateful of you would take a look at it :)

Comment: Option 1 is not working but second option works fine. Thanks.